# Type checking is not happening for nested object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, typeguards

I am working on an Angular application. In that I have an interface `IAbc`:

```js
interface IAbc {
    id: number,
    name: string
}
```

And another interface `IXyz` which uses the above interface like below:

```js
interface IXyz {
    id: number,
    value: string | number | Date | IAbc[];
}
```

Here, the value can be of any type of data, so I have narrowed down on the types.

I have created a new variable:

```js
let someVar: IXyz;

someVar = {
    id: 100,
    value: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'abc'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'xyz'
        }
    ]
};
```

Since the value can be a list also, I have to use `forEach` on it to do some operation:

```js
someVar.value.forEach((x: IAbc) => console.log('some operation on value, ', x))
```

But, I get this error on `forEach`:

```
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string | number | Date | IAbc[]'.
  Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'.(2339)
```

I think logically this should work. Is there something wrong with the typescript?

I have created a playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEBGDkG8BQyRywAJgFzIgCuAtptADSHEhy0SUDOYUoA5vgC++fKEixEKVAA0AngC88LImUo16TFcgBucADbVOyHnxD9kAHyp0GUK8gAicSA4zYA2gF0A3MNH6EGAmAPYcAGpwUJSyin74XGEQkfYAvMrEJBTIAIwADHnMmXqGxh7amQSZ1cRquUU11WwclADkcNitFcRCDTVVjZl1AEx9g1Tsxq0AHopdgyKZXv4JSSkAdCVG6zAhUACiiAAWABQn0zFYCACUyKkAfMgIISCJgev6IfwnrYkcyCEAA7QFzAF4AkC6AxGRjIVqw6bXa74IA), where I have reproduced this.

Let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

---

P.S.: I know I can use `any` over there and it will work smoothly, but the usage of `any` has been disabled by the linting of the application.

Comment: "*Is there something wrong with the typescript?*" No, nothing wrong. You've declare the type to be `string | number | Date | IAbc[]` hence TS doesn't assume it's just one of the four and requires you to make sure before you use the code. Sure, it wouldn't have changed but TS doesn't track that, it just looks at the type.

Comment: You can assert that the `value` property is indeed an array by using `as`. `(someVar.value as IAbc[]).forEach ...`. This will fail when the value is any of the other types, as the `forEach` method doesn't exist on any of them.

Comment: @VLAZ, I think it would be nice and easy, if TS did it by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error you can use a typeguard.

```
function isArray(value: string | number | Date | IAbc[]): value is IAbc[] {
  return (value as IAbc[]).forEach !== undefined;
}

if( isArray(someVar.value) ) {
    someVar.value.forEach((x: IAbc) => console.log('some operation on value, ', x))
}
```

You can see it working in an updated version of your playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEBGDkG8BQyRywAJgFzIgCuAtptADSHEhy0SUDOYUoA5vgC%20%20fKEixEKVAA0AngC88LImUo16TFcgBucADbVOyHnxD9kAHyp0GUK8gAicSA4zYA2gF0A3MNEw1CAIYMAA9iAkXOhQUHByABR6hsamAg4adg7OrtbuCN4AlJTJRlFoWAVeykRQEGDUUJFJBmVwXBWeXoUAdDBhUACiiAAWyACEALyTyEGkEDCgEKR%20Ivj69SZhHABqcFCUsop%20%20FzbEHv2MwTEJBTIAIwADE-Mt6XGHtq3N7d-qvcHm9-n82BxKAByODYCHfYhCYH-X4g4hqZAAJkRKKo7GMEIAHopYSiRLcvP4xDAElEYnFEmddvseh9CshWcitoyoMzWhA%20gNhggRgkEvjDpVWZMAHzIBARM4bHr6ML8BIQhkoMIAB2gLnCkQiul5jGQEJN%20MKhX8QA)

Answer (score -1):

You need a typecast to tell the compiler this is indeed an array

```js
(someVar.value as IAbc[]).forEach((x: IAbc) => console.log('some operation on value, ', x))
```